Canon PowerShot A80 keeps shutting down and asking to change the battery pack. What should I do?
I have a Canon PowerShot A80 - which is obviously an old camera - dating back to 2003. Everytime I take one or two shots, it switches itself off, stating to change the battery pack. I changed a few types of battery, but it stays the same. Any idea how to solve this? Because I tried pushing the spring against the door more and also tried taking out the battery and memory card and leaving it for 20 minutes. There is no rust in the battery compartment - I even cleaned it.

It's not clear to me that you are methodically replacing bad batteries with known good ones. It sounds to me like you are doing it a bit haphazardly.

Perhaps the button cell needs changing too.

Are you using Alakalines?  Heavy-duty and NiMH batteries may have too low a voltage.

@WeatherVane it doesn't have a button cell, but a "built-in rechargeable lithium battery" so probably not replaceable

@davolfman NiMH are stated as not just compatible but recommended, in the manual.

@ChrisH where did you find that? Can't think of any significant reason to add lithium cell to a camera.

@EuriPinhollow in the user manual: pp26-28 going by the print page numbers, from p30 of the PDF.

@ChrisH  NiMH work, but in my experience they run out much faster with the A series, and that's when the camera's in perfect working order. I gave up on them and switched to alkalines. I think they really only work at the peak of their voltage.  So if the camera's degraded, and the battery's degraded they may not work for long at all.

@ChrisH the four AA batteries are not built-in, but are alkaline or rechargeable NiMH, as shown on page 24 (20) of the manual in your link. They are the main power source, but there is often another battery to retain the settings when the batteries are changed.

Note that the nominal voltage of rechargeable AA cells is often around 1.2 instead of the 1.5 volts from alkaline or zinc batteries. Perhaps the aging camera needs the full voltage.

@WeatherVane yes, 4AA for main power, which is why I talk about cleaning the contacts. Then a little built in rechargeable Li to keep the clock. If it needs 6V now when 4.8V was enough before that's a proper failure rather than just age. But new alkalines are the best test anyway. Old NiMH can take charge but have a high internal resistance or deplete almost instantly

@davolfman I used like heavy duty type batteries…I will try alkaline one if I can find it

@ChrisH  but then the manual also says that if cell got bad the date will just reset, not like there will be something worse.

@EuriPinhollow that's true, but go back through the thread and you'll see that I'm only dismissing the possibility of changing a button cell that doesn't exist, not commenting on what a dodgy clock battery would do

If you're testing with rechargeable batteries, even freshly charged, try it with brand new alkalines. NiMH cells don't last for ever and they can fail by losing nearly all of their capacity or getting a high internal resistance. Either of those will cause the camera to see a low voltage.
Assuming alkalines from a new pack don't help, at this point you've got nothing to lose by trying a couple of things.  Both of these risk damage or even total destruction
Battery Terminals
Even though you've checked, I would want to get into the battery compartment and look not for rust but for the corrosion caused by leaked batteries.  Rust (iron oxide) is brown, but what you'd get if batteries had leaked is much paler and harder to spot deep inside a battery compartment.  "Cleaning" as you say you've done with a dry or damp cloth, or any likely chemicals, won't do much.
Some people say you can remove it with a pencil eraser but I've never had much luck.  very fine sandpaper is the way to go, either on the end of a flat rod or after disassembly.  You need to remove every trace from the contact points.  It's highly insulating and even a speck will prevent contact with the conductive metal.
External Power Supply
Canon made an external power supply for this camera, part number ACK600.  It may still be available, or third party equivalents are; they claim to be 4.3V (surprisingly low given that alkaline batteries add up to 6V and NiMH to 4.8V).  It has a fairly standard barrel connector. If you have a selection of old power supplies, as I do, I'd look for one of 4.3V or slightly more (but definitely not over 6V, and don't put batteries in at the same time if >4.3V in case it tries to charge them) and a suitable connector, and splice them together.  I can't find the polarity online but it may be marked on the camera.  If not I'd try centre positive.

Thanks I will try it

It is working fine with the external power supply

Good news.  Now you have to choose whether to use it like that (I use a DSLR of similar age almost exclusively with a power supply) or to keep trying to sort the battery issues

Great it is working fine with alkaline batteries…thanks


any idea how to solve this?

Get a new camera.
I'm no fan of disposable tech culture, but we're talking about a 21 year old device here. It's done it's job, time to move on.

I second that. If a fresh set of four AA alkaline batteries also exhibits the problem, then this thing is gone to where toasters go to rest in peace.

Note that the OP's link is headed Canon camera museum :)

@WeatherVane Note that link was not added by the OP. Let me know if you want to delete these comments.

There may be a number or reasons for the OP to want to use THAT camera. It's wrong to dismiss them. In the end the problem was solved very easily using alkaline batteries. Sometimes we just overthink.

If you tried new batteries and it says so then it's malfunctioning and you cannot fix it without disassembling it. Oxidation could indeed cause this problem but you've already checked for it.

When I need to clean battery terminals, I simply use an ink eraser. Cheap, replaceable and usable for its intended purpose.
